# XCode: macosx10.11 (SDK not found) --- how can I compile to run on my 10.11 machine?

Tags: xcode, macos

I would like to compile an old Max OS X console application that I was developing in XCode a while ago, but I've upgraded something since then and attempting to build it gives me an error that I don't know how to fix. This happens to me a lot.

In this case, the error is

> The run desination My Mac is not valid for Running the scheme 'GLTest'.

which pops up in a modal dialogue when I press CMD-B.

Looking in the build settings, I see that the Base SDK is set to "macosx10.11 (SDK not found)". I'm running 10.11, so that looks like it might be the problem.

Answers to similar questions suggest either re-installing everything or doing some sneaky stuff with symlinks or plist files, but I'm sure that I *did* manage to build one of my other old projects when this problem arose, just by fiddling around in the build settings. So I suspect I just have to select the correct option in some drop down or other and everything will be OK, I just can't seem to hit on the right one.

TL;DR: I'm running OS X 10.11 and would like to build a console application in XCode to run on my own machine. How can I accomplish this trivial task?

Answer (score 1):

After some more aimless scrabbling around in the build settings, I found the answer. Hopefully it will be useful to others. There are two steps:

1. Set the 'Base SDK' to 10.12, even though I'm running 10.11
2. search for "macOS deployment target" and change it to 10.11

That's it, it works after that.

(If anyone wants to post an answer explaining *why* this works, i.e. how the XCode build system works and what those terms mean in relation to it, that would be super helpful and I'll accept such an answer.)